# Digest md5 response generation

Tags: md5, digest, rfc, digest-authentication, sasl

How to generate response field in client response for DIGEST MD5 challenge, I'am currently using [rfc 2831](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2831.txt)  for reference

Challenge from server as per rfc 2831 example is:

```
realm="elwood.innosoft.com",nonce="OA6MG9tEQGm2hh",qop="auth",
algorithm=md5-sess,charset=utf-8
```

response from client as per rfc 2831 example :

```
charset=utf-8,username="chris",realm="elwood.innosoft.com",
nonce="OA6MG9tEQGm2hh",nc=00000001,cnonce="OA6MHXh6VqTrRk",
digest-uri="imap/elwood.innosoft.com",
response=d388dad90d4bbd760a152321f2143af7,qop=auth
```

---

collected details are:

1. username=chris
2. password=secret
3. nonce=OA6MG9tEQGm2hh
4. nc-value=00000001
5. cnonce=OA6MHXh6VqTrRk
6. qop=auth
7. realm=elwood.innosoft.com
8. digesturi=imap/elwood.innosoft.com

---

Response I'm generating doesn't comply with that in rfc 2831 example at page 19

Formulations in rfc 2831

Let H(s) be the 16 octet MD5 hash [RFC 1321] of the octet string s.

Let KD(k, s) be H({k, ":", s}), i.e., the 16 octet hash of the string k, a colon and the string s.

Let HEX(n) be the representation of the 16 octet MD5 hash n as a string of 32 hex digits (with alphabetic characters always in lower case, since MD5 is case sensitive).

---

Currently i'am using following procedure:

A1 = { H(chris:elwood.innosoft.com:secret), ":", nonce-value, ":", cnonce-value }

[online md5 generator](http://www.freeformatter.com/md5-generator.html)

A1 = {eb5a750053e4d2c34aa84bbc9b0b6ee7:OA6MG9tEQGm2hh:OA6MHXh6VqTrRk}

A2       = { "AUTHENTICATE:", digest-uri-value }
A2       = {AUTHENTICATE:imap/elwood.innosoft.com}

H(A1) = 54442ff1f394d9d0de1205cef4d9cebe

HEX(H(A1)) = 54442ff1f394d9d0de1205cef4d9cebe

HEX(H(A2)) = 15e3594677e51ade69715d1cb7d207ba

---

RESPONSE=HEX( KD ( HEX(H(A1)), { nonce-value, ":" nc-value, ":", cnonce-value, ":", qop-value, ":", HEX(H(A2)) }))

RESPONSE=HEX( KD ( 54442ff1f394d9d0de1205cef4d9cebe:OA6MG9tEQGm2hh:00000001:OA6MHXh6VqTrRk:auth:15e3594677e51ade69715d1cb7d207ba))

Response as per above procedure is:

## 26ef1190b643a36e879673066098379c

---

but response value as per rfc is :

## d388dad90d4bbd760a152321f2143af7

Thus response generated above is different from one generated in rfc's example

what changes need to be carried out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, RFC documentation is right, you just miscalculated the hash of A1.

Because, you converted hash value of "H(chris:elwood.innosoft.com:secret)" to hex string. But RFC just says "Let H(s) be the 16 octet MD5 hash".

Just, don't convert hash result to hex string and concatenate with this byte array hash result.

I hope this code helps to explain.

```
A1 = Md5Hash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + realm + ":" + password))
     .Concat(
        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
          ":" + nonce
        + ":" + cnonce
        + (authzid == null ? "" : (":" + authzid))))
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A1 calculation is wrong. The MD5 digest over chris:elwood.innosoft.com:secret in your case is 32-octet hexadecimal, 2 octets per original byte. In the RFC calculation it is 16-octet, 1 octet = 1 byte.

Answer (score -3):

You have calculated response correctly and example in RFC2831 is not consistent.